# parse error before '' *2

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "char.h"
#include "user.h"

bool user::readYN (string ans)
{
    ans = tolower (ans);
    if (ans == "y" || ans == "yes")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (ans == "n" || ans == "no")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<playr.inputErr;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The string ans is passed to it from my main.cpp and should be a y\n to confirm a charecter name. However whenever I try to compile this I get the error

> user.cpp:6: parse error before '{'

and the errer

> user.cpp:8: parse error before '+'

I have no idea where it is getting an error for the { and I don't know where it see's a +(my thinking is the equal... maybe???) All my other code has compiled and I just want to start actually building stuff.

EDIT: By request the header files are as follows

user.h

```
#ifndef user
#define user

#include<string>
class user
{
    public:
        string input;
        static string inputErr;
        bool readYN(string);
        void read(string);

}playr;

#endif
```

and char.h

```
#ifndef chara
#define chara

#include<string>
class charecter
{
    public:
        string name;
        bool yes;
        int HP;
        void nameMe(string);
}chara;

#endif
```

Comment: Try replacing string with std::string

Comment: There's no `+` in the code you posted. Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: Yeah I copy pasted it. Why I am confused about it being there

Comment: maybe `tolower` used as macro? AFAIK `tolower` can get `char` not a string. and yes, you're missing `namespace std`.

Comment: What is in user.h? I assume you have a `using namespace std` in there (which you [shouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) btw).

Comment: @ArtoriusIV `#include "char.h"
#include "user.h"` probably something wrong in these non standard header files. But you don't disclose unfortunately :-( ...

Comment: I still get the line 6 error without tolower, thought I do not get the line 8 error

Comment: @ArtoriusIV Please disclose what these header files are about, especially `user.h`!

Comment: I changed the user in the '#indef' and '#define' to userA and I no longer got these issues

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
bool user::readYN (string ans)
```

to

```
bool user::readYN (std::string ans)
```

Comment: I did that but no change in compilation errors. Care to explain why that should have fixed it?

Comment: @ArtoriusIV: Since you used `std::cout` (and not just `cout`), it is perfectly logical to expect that you need `std::string` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. The defining in user.h screwed with the class declaration.

Comment: It's always good to use a naming convention for the `#include` guard macros that makes sure that it doesn't conflict with the name of class.. E.g. `USER_H` or `USER_HEADER`.